# Python line of unindented code is said to be in a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

In a discord bot program I'm working on, I have a function that reads

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith(';hello'):
        await message.channel.send('Hello dirtbag')

    if message.content.startswith(';bitcoin price'):
        answer = bitcoin_price()ON
        await message.channel.send("The current price of bitcoin is ' + answer + ' USD')
```

And then right under it I have

```
client.run(TOKEN)
```

but the bottom line doesn't work, and my editor (Virtual studio code) shows that it is in the on_message function, even though it is unindented. I also tried adding both `pass` and `return` at the end of the function, but it still didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this line replace " with '

```
await message.channel.send("The current price of bitcoin is ' + answer + ' USD')
```

to

```
await message.channel.send('The current price of bitcoin is ' + answer + ' USD')
```